# Coping constructor not called when returning by value

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)
>   [why isn’t the copy constructor called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154290/why-isnt-the-copy-constructor-called)

Why in the following code both gcc and clang don't call copy constructor of A class even one 
time (there is only one object created as destructor is called only one time).

```
class A
{
public:
  explicit A()
  {
    std::cout << "A()" << std::endl;
  }
  A(const A& toCp)
  {
    std::cout << "A(const A&)" << std::endl;
  }
  ~A()
  {
    std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl;
  }
  A& operator=(const A& toCp)
  {
    std::cout << "A::operator=" << std::endl;
  }
};

A fun()
{
  A x;
  std::cout << "fun" << std::endl;
  return x;
}

int main()
{
  A u = fun();
  return 0;
}
```

Printout of this code is:

```
A()
fun
~A()
```

I thought it copy constructor should be called 2 times (one for returning value and one in line `A u = fun(7);`

I used gcc and clang with -O0 for this code.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) try passing `-fno-elide-constructors` to GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler uses **copy elision** to avoid a copy (or move) for the return value of function `fun()`. This is a standard and trivial optimization which will almost always be invoked (depending on the compiler and its optimisation settings). The compiler may do this even if the elided copy (or move) constructor would have had side effects (as in your case, where it writes to stdout).

*note* Copy elision is not restricted to `inline` functions, but will be used even if the function definition lives in a different compilation unit.